# Why "not equal" (!=) in if statement within for loop returns only one row

Tags: python, csv

I have the following csv data and I want to filter it to just pull 8PM,apple,table

```
1,8PM,apple,table,yes
2,8PM,apple,table,no
3,6PM,carrot,chair,no
4,7PM,berries,table,no
5,8PM,apple,table,yes
6,6PM,banana,table,no
7,8PM,carrot,chair,no
8,7PM,carrot,table,no
9,8PM,guava,chair,no
10,7PM,guava,table,yes
11,8PM,apple,table,no
```

I tried to test '==',

```
if each[1] == '8PM' and each[2] == 'apple' and each[3] == 'table':
```

and it gives the expected result:

```
['1', '8PM', 'apple', 'table', 'yes']
['2', '8PM', 'apple', 'table', 'no']
['5', '8PM', 'apple', 'table', 'yes']
['11', '8PM', 'apple', 'table', 'no']
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    pool = list(reader)
    for each in pool:
        if each[1] != '8PM' and each[2] != 'apple' and each[3] != 'table':
            print(each)
```

For the actual result, I'm only getting one row:

```
['3', '6PM', 'carrot', 'chair', 'no']
```

I'm expecting the following:

```
['3', '6PM', 'carrot', 'chair', 'no']
['4', '7PM', 'berries', 'table', 'no']
['6', '6PM', 'banana', 'table', 'no']
['7', '8PM', 'carrot', 'chair', 'no']
['8', '7PM', 'carrot', 'table', 'no']
['9', '8PM', 'guava', 'chair', 'no']
['10', '7PM', 'guava', 'table', 'yes']
```

Comment: Only if the second column is *not* `8PM`, etc. You probably want to replace `and` with `or`.

Answer (score 1):

The negation of *x∧y* is *(¬x)∨(¬y)*. So that means you need to substitute `and` with `or`, like:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    pool = list(reader)
    for each in pool:
        if each[1] != '8PM' or each[2] != 'apple' or each[3] != 'table':
            print(each)
```

or if you do not want to use [*de Morgan's laws* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan_law), you can simply use `not` in front, like:

```
import csv
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    pool = list(reader)
    for each in pool:
        if not (each[1] == '8PM' and each[2] == 'apple' and each[3] == 'table'):
            print(each)
```

Comment: The first code "!= '8PM' or" returned all 11 rows. While the second returned my expected result. Appreciate your time!

Comment: @orpheum: If I run this locally, I get seven rows for both the first and the second one.

Comment: You are right @Willem. I ran it again and got seven rows. I think I missed something on the first try. So both first and second works perfectly. Appreciate you pointing that out and link to de Morgan's laws.